# Union option in thinking sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have more than two has attributes defined in my model, Is there any way to combine both the results together.i.e, an OR of the results. Usually when I do a search on the model it does an AND operation of the results.

```
Article.search(:with => {:abc => 1, :xyz => 1})
```

I want to know whether there any way to combine the results of both the attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sphinx itself, doesnt support 'OR' between filters.

See
http://sphinxsearch.com/info/faq/#filter-or

can use Select to compute a virtual attribute (but dont know how to specify it in Thinking-Sphinx) - or do it in full text fields.